# FPDF: Output PDF using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fpdf

I have a PHP file where I generate a PDF file using FPDF. If I execute that file, it generates and loads the pdf file on browser. However when I try to generate the PDF file using a button and by using AJAX it does not work.

I am using AJAX since I need to post some variables to PHP to make a query in the database before generating the PDF file.

I looked for solutions on internet but I still do not know how to achieve this.

**I want to load the pdf on browser, not download it**

PHP:

```
$pdf->Output('name.pdf','I');
```

AJAX:

```
var IDDocument = 15;
var Document = 'Invoice';
var ClientID = '205160615';

    $.ajax({  
                type: 'POST', 
                url: 'PDF.php',  
                data: { IDDocument:IDDocument, 
                        Document:Document,  
                        ClientID:ClientID, 
                        btnPDF:'btnPDF'},
                success: function(data) {
                    //load PDF on browser.
                }
            });

            return false;
```

Comment: Whether or not the PDF will be downloaded by the browser automatically is up to the user in almost all cases. If you use the `string` output option of fPDF (`$ourpdf->Output('S')`) you may set the headers and send along your PDF.

Comment: It does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

I decided to use JQuery to make a POST to a PHP file like this:

```
function f()
    {
        //Variables I needed to POST to PHP

        var IDDocument = 15;
        var Document = 'Invoice';
        var ClientID = '205160615';

        //POST to PHP using JQUERY

        $.post('PDF.php'{
                         IDDocument:IDDocument, 
                         Document:Document,
                         ClientID:ClientID,
                         btnPDF:"btnPDF"//btnPDF is just to check if user clicked the button
                         }, 

                         function() //this function is to call the PHP File a second time
                         {
                            window.open('PDF.php');
                         });

    }
```

Then, in the PHP File I decided to store the variables sent in `$_SESSION` variables after making sure the user clicked the button by using an `if` condition. And then, the second time the PHP file is called, as the user did not clicked the button I checked that using an `else` in oder to create and load the PDF file this time. Since I have the variables previously stored in `$_SESSION` variables, I just used them to load the PDF file and then I unset them.

this is the code in the PHP file:

```
if(isset($_POST['btnPDF'])) //Check if user clicked the button
{
   //If the user clicked the button, store the variables in $_SESSION variables         

    $_SESSION["IDDocument"]=$_POST['IDDocument'];
    $_SESSION["Document"]=$_POST['Document'];
    $_SESSION["ClientID"]=$_POST['ClientID'];
}
else
{
   //the second time the PHP file is called, the user didn't clicked the button.
   //This second time I use the $_SESSION variables previously stored in the first
   //call to the PHP file in order to create and load the PDF file

    //asign $_SESSION variables to PHP variables if you want to

    $IDDocument=$_SESSION["IDDocument"];
    $Document=$_SESSION["Document"]; 
    $ClientID=$_SESSION["ClientID"];

    //unset the $_SESSION variables

    unset($_SESSION["IDDocument"],$_SESSION["Document"],$_SESSION["ClientID"]);

    //Create and load the PDF file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may redirect the browser (on success) to the generated pdf file. The url could be fetch via the ajax response.

Example:

```js
$.ajax({  
    type: 'POST', 
    url: 'PDF.php',  
    data: { IDDocumento:IDDocumento, 
            TipoDocumento:TipoDocumento,  
            CedulaCliente:CedulaCliente, 
            btnPDF:'btnPDF'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // redirect to the generated pdf file
        window.location = data.url;
    }
});
```

The URL for the PDF file must be generated on the server side (in PHP).

```php
<?php
// pdf.php

// Generate PDF here
// ...

// Generate url
// Use an UUID to make sure that nobody can guess the url
$url = 'filename-with-uuid.pdf';

// Send json response
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(['url' => $url]);
```

Comment: But how do I get the URL for the created PDF?

Comment: The URL must be generated on the server side (in PHP).

Answer (score 0):

here's what i ended up doing:

```
$.post(ajaxurl,data,function(html, response){
      $(responsediv).html(html)
}
```

then on php side i simply echo'd back and iframe with the url to the pdf file set

```
$_SESSION['data']=$_POST['data']
echo <iframe src=pdf.php style="width:100%;height:100vh"
```

and then finally in the pdf.php

i have the pdf generation code

```
$pdf->Output('name.pdf',I);
```