# Show FPDF in browser, using the Ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp, fpdf

Putting together [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59523070/881712) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3825419/881712), I'm trying to load the generated pdf into a new window using the Ajax response:

**JavaScript**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token': <?= json_encode($this->request->getParam('_csrfToken')); ?> },
  url:  '<?php echo Router::url(['controller' => 'DeliveryNotes', 'action' => 'pdf']);?>',
  data: { 'type': result },
  success: function(response) {
    var w = window.open('about:blank');
    w.document.open();
    w.document.write(response);
    w.document.close();
  }
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function pdf($id = null)
{
    if ($this->request->is(['ajax', 'get'])) {
        $type = $this->request->getData('type');

        require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'fpdf' . DS . 'fpdf' . DS . 'original' . DS . 'fpdf.php');
        $this->response = $this->response->withType('pdf');
        $this->response = $this->response->withHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="some.pdf"');
        $this->layout = 'pdf';
        $this->set('fpdf', new FPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4'));
        $this->set('type', $type);
        $this->render('pdf');
    }
}
```

**Layout**

```
<?php
    echo $content;
```

**View**

```
<?php
    $fpdf->AddPage();
    $fpdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $fpdf->Cell(40,10, $type);
    $this->set('content', $fpdf->Output('S'));
```

It opens a new window but shows the raw content instead of the actual pdf.
Instead, if I just invoke the controller action (without the Ajax request, like in the first answer linked) it works.

Perhaps the headers are not transferred to the new window?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550809/fpdf-output-pdf-using-ajax) there's a possible solution, but as far as I understand it requires to create an actual pdf file on the server. Instead, I don't want to create such a file: I want to pass the pdf content to the browser directly.

### UPDATE

A workaround that achieves the same goal without Ajax is the following:

**Javascript**

```
let url = new URL('<?= Router::url(['controller' => 'DeliveryNotes', 'action' => 'pdf'], true); ?>');
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('type', result);
params.append('id', id);
window.open(url + '?' + params, '_blank');
```

**Controller**

```
public function pdf()
{
    $type = $this->request->getQuery('type');
    $id = $this->request->getQuery('id');

    require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'fpdf' . DS . 'fpdf' . DS . 'original' . DS . 'fpdf.php');
    $this->response = $this->response->withType('pdf');
    $this->response = $this->response->withHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="some.pdf"');
    $this->layout = 'pdf';
    $this->set('fpdf', new FPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4'));
    $this->set('id', $id);
    $this->set('type', $type);
    $this->render('pdf');
}
```

It's not the best solution because in the new window the controller's action and the query parameter (`type` and `id`) are both visible. But at least works.

Any suggestion to do the same using Ajax is appreciated!

Comment: missing content type header

Comment: @felixmosh, without the Ajax call it wasn't required. Anyway adding `$this->response = $this->response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');` changes nothing.

Comment: i had the same issue, i think i tried alot, and i end up with iframe, and also you can save the pdf and then open it using windows.open

Comment: @AhmedSunny, yes saving the file and opening after works. But I really don't want to create a file on the server, as said.

Comment: If you want to display the PDF in a popup, then opening the PDF URL in a new window isn't a workaround, but the correct solution for this problem.